# How to prevent collection of removing model when destroyed?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

Is there a way to prevent backbone.js collection of removing my model when it gets detroyed?

Everytime it happens I receive a "remove" trigger event from collection

```
collection.on("remove", this.handleRemove)
```

already tried passing some arguments but nothing

`model.destroy({silent: false, remove: false})`

Comment: Why would you want that? If something doesn't exist any longer, how can it be collected?

Comment: actually the model.destroy still persist the object on the client side. I would like to manipulate it after and eventually saving again without creating a new model and add to collection

Comment: My problem is that I have model-view with an editable textarea and when it`s typing I call POST/UPDATE, but if the text is empty I should DELETE but not remove the view, because the user can still type after that (creating/deleting a single model on the same view)

Comment: the only issue is that all my list view is based on my collection events, and when some model is destroyed it update with deleting the "subview", but I only want it to fire when collection.remove(myModel) and not myModel.destroy()

Comment: You should describe your real needs in the question, I have understood you after read the comments. As I see it you are not comfortable with the default `destroy` event behavior so you should implement [your custom event](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events)

Comment: Not knowing how your front-end application works I can only comment on the fact that doing a DELETE when there is no text is horrible User Experience, there should be a DELETE button or a clear indication that you're removing the item. Based on that, if the ID of the model on the client won't correspond with the ID on the server, you're better off creating a new "empty" model that has no ID, just a ClientID (`cid`) and thus a new `CreateItemView`. There are certain conventions that Backbone sticks to and your path breaks those.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to override the Backbone model destroy function. I made this on an abstract model with success and callback strategy:

Parameter "data" corresponds to the original parameter "resp".

```
destroy: function(successCallback, errorCallback) 
{
    var options = { wait: true };
    var model = this;

    successCallback = successCallback || function() {};
    errorCallback = errorCallback || function() {};               

    var destroy = function() 
    {
        model.trigger('destroy', model, model.collection, options);
    };

    options.success = function(data) 
    {
        if ('SUCCESS' === data.responseCode)
        {
            if (options.wait || model.isNew())
                destroy();

             successCallback(data);

            if (!model.isNew())
                model.trigger('sync', model, data, options);
        }
        else
        {
            errorCallback(data);
        }
    };

    if (this.isNew()) 
    {
        options.success();
        return false;
    }

    var xhr = this.sync('delete', this, options);

    if (!options.wait)
        destroy();

    return xhr;
}
```